# How to get JSON from JSP and insert it into Angular's Model?

Tags: json, angularjs, servlets

I'm new in Angularjs and Javascript and now I'm trying to create a Java Objet and I converted it in JSON. Then I try to catch this JSON from Angular's Controller and display it as an Angular's Model, but now I can't find my JSON in my browser when I run my application. In my JSP I've a simple code :

```
<html data-ng-app="mathsApp">
    <head>
        <title>Calcul des racines</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-cale=1.0">
        <script src = "js/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body  >
        <%
            Car vago = new Car(1500, 6);
            org.json.JSONObject jso = new JSONObject();
            jso.put("vago", vago);                
        %>

        <!-- this line works fine -->
        <p data-ng-controller="monControl">  {{temps}}   </p>
        <!-- this line not works, here I'm trying to get my JSON -->
        <p data-ng-controller="monControl">  {{test}}  </p>        

    </body>
</html>
```

and my controller :

```
var MathsApp = angular.module('mathsApp', []);

MathsApp.controller('monControl', function($scope, $http)
{     
    $scope.temps = 'pluie';

    $scope.test = http.get("http://localhost:8080/Angular_On_J2EE/index.jsp")
    .success(function(data) 
        {
            $scope.names = data;
        }
    );     
});
```

Please, someone could tell me what's wrong here ?
Thanks in advance and sorry for my english but I'm loving this awesome community.

Comment: I'm assuming the first code piece is the `index.jsp` page on `Angular_On_J2EE`, is that correct?

Comment: That's right this code is included in index.jsp.

Comment: You have to create a new file that returns only the `JSONObject`

Answer (score 0):

I think your second line to print should be

```
<p data-ng-controller="monControl">  {{names}}  </p>
```

Because you are storing the JSON in `names`(*inside success function of controller*
) variable not in `test`.